# Rationalizing the fraction $\frac{1}{1-\sqrt2 -\sqrt3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, rationalising-denominator

I'm having problem in rationalizing the following root with the fraction $$\frac{1}{1-\sqrt2 -\sqrt3}$$
Eventually after many tries, I found the solution which was : $$\frac{-\sqrt2 (1-\sqrt2 +\sqrt3 )}{4}$$
But I want to know if there's a specific method to use in a case like this.
Thanks

Comment: You multiply top and bottom by all the conjugates of the denominator. In this case, by $(1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3)(1+\sqrt2-\sqrt3)(1-\sqrt2+\sqrt3)$.

Comment: Alternatively, you write $1/(1-\sqrt2-\sqrt3)=a+b\sqrt2+c\sqrt3+d\sqrt6$, multiply both sides by $1-\sqrt2-\sqrt3$, multiply out the right side, and equate coefficients on the two sides, giving four equations in the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: I give up, its very uneditable and I might as well change the original content. [Use this link to] edit(http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)}=\frac{1}{1-(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)}\frac{1+(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)}{1+(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)}=$$
$$=\frac{1+(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)}{1-(5 +2\sqrt6)}=\frac{1+(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)}{2(\sqrt6-2)}=$$
$$=\frac{1+(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)}{2(\sqrt6-2)}\frac{\sqrt6+2}{\sqrt6+2}=\frac{(1+\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)(\sqrt2 +\sqrt3)}{64}$$

Answer (score 0):

When I rationalize I always admire the property
     $$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$$
Using this fact try stating $a=1$ and $b=\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$.
You will get another situation where you are going to use this property again but to answer your question if you have square root in your denominator then try to put it in the form of $(a-b)$ form and finally multiply both the numerator and denominator by $(a + b)$.

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.